# Example of Topologically Mixing map on $k$-dimensional cube

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Let $k,M$ be positive integers.  Is there a simply *explicit* example of a topologically mixing map on:

- The "cube" $[-1,1]^k$?
- The "disc" $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^k: \|x\|\leq 1\}$?

And what are the points therein with dense, periodic orbits...

Since the product of topologically transitive maps need not be topologically transitive, I cannot build an example from the $1$-dimensional case.

Comment: The canonical example would be a hyperbolic toral automorphism. See, e.g., pp 45-46 of https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/john_smillie/maths_4240/ma424_notes_2013.pdf . This example should also be in pretty much any dynamics textbook.

Comment: I didn't find the example outside of $k=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know the tent map $T\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map)? It's a piecewise linear map, with $T(0)=0=T(1)$ and $T(\frac{1}{2})=1$. It has this property, that if you iterate it, its graph will look like many peaks, and for any open subset $U\subset [0,1]$ there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n>N$ we have $T^n(U)=[0,1]$. It's much stronger then topological mixing and if you take $\Pi^k T\colon [0,1]^k\to[0,1]^k$ it will also have this property, so you should be able to do the cube.

Comment: Good example, but cube is not homeomorphic to the sphere, you should correct the claim.

Comment: Corrected. You are right

Answer (score 1):

**Expanding example on the torus: the doubling map.**

A simple mixing example for the torus, $\mathbb T^k = [0,1]^k/\sim$, is simply the doubling map in $k$ dimensions:

$$f:(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k) \mapsto (2 x_1,2 x_2, \ldots 2x_k) \mod 1.$$

I.e., $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k) \mapsto \left(D(x_1), D(x_2), \ldots D(x_k)\right)$, where $D:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is the one dimensional doubling map, passed to the quotient:

$$D(x) = \begin{cases} 2x & 0 \le x \le \frac12, \\ 2x - 1 & \frac12 < x\le 1.\end{cases}$$

*Heuristic: why it mixes.*

This $f$ mixes for the same reasons as $D$ in one dimension. Namely, given an interval $I$ of length $l>0$ in $[0,1]$, whenever $ n > - \log_2 (l)$, we have $f^n(I)=[0,1]$.

This argument can be generalised to $k$ dimensions as follows:

Every open set contains a small $k$-cube. All of the dimensions of this cube are being enlarged by a factor of $2$ with each iteration of the map, and so with enough iterates will engulf the whole cube $Q$.

That is, for all open sets $U$, for large enough $n$ (depending on the minimum length of $U$); $f^n(U) = \mathbb T$, and in particular meets every other open set $V$ in the cube.

*This example generalises to:*
Take any matrix $A \in \text{GL}_k(\mathbb Z)$ with integer entries, such that all eigenvalues are strictly outside the unit disk ($|\lambda|> 1$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$).

Then $x\mapsto A x \mod 1$ has similar properties to the doubling map, above.

The harder generalisation of @erfink is that of an Anosov map, where you insist that no eigenvalues of $A$ lie on the unit circle (we may also require $\det(A)=1$), examples being

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\qquad
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & 2 & 1 \\
 2 & 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
and so on.

Comment: So just to be sure I got it right.  An n-fold application of this would be equal to applying $x\to (2^n)x  \mod 1$ Right?

Comment: The usual definition of a topologically mixing map requires continuity of the map.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I guess this should be specified by the asker. For instance, in the definition from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3476579/question-about-an-example-of-topologocally-mixing-map) question the continuity is not required.

Comment: @AnnieLeKatsu, yes, this is true.

Comment: @MoisheKohan This is probably why these maps are normally stated as acting on the torus. Perhaps if continuity is desired, then perhaps one should use a tent map–style construction like in the other answer.

Comment: @GoodBoy Right.

Comment: Why haven't I get 100 reward? :( I was first. I feel intentionally ignored.

Comment: And anyway if continuity is not required then why don't we just take some weird function, for example throw rationals to zero and take some countable basis, and map some dense subset of each element of this basis to some dense subset of cube, it will also work. I mean... no continuity in (!) topological (!) mixing?

Comment: Okay, my mistake: I've been working on the torus as of late. However, I can't delete it now its been accepted. Perhaps I should make it a community wiki so that you can correct it to have the details of the tent example?

Comment: @pem I feel bad now I didn't see the answer originally :0 :(

Comment: @GoodBoy Yes that would be good.  I hadn't initially notived the discontinuity.  I'll un accept the answer then and some details on the tent construction can be added to the community post?

Comment: @GoodBoy  Do you have a link to this doubling map, I liked it very much even if it isn't continuous... it works better for the application I cared about since its even nice to implement..

Comment: Sure: it features in a lot of first-courses on ergodic theory, which you can find with a simple google. Some examples include [this](https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/charles.walkden/magic/lecture01.pdf#page=5), [this](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maslav/Teaching/warwick_ergodic_notes.pdf#page=2) and [this](http://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/users/irene.pasquinelli/dyn/CorinnaII.pdf#page=6). There is even a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_transformation).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to clarify the definition. I checked two  standard dynamical systems references:

*Brin, Michael; Stuck, Garrett*, [**Introduction to dynamical systems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511755316), Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-1-107-53894-8/pbk; 978-0-511-75531-6/ebook). xii, 240 p. (2015). [ZBL1319.37001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1319.37001).

*Katok, Anatole; Hasselblatt, Boris*, Introduction to the modern theory of dynamical systems, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Its Applications. 54. Cambridge: Cambridge Univ. Press. xviii, 802 p. (1995). [ZBL0878.58020](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0878.58020).

as well as the [this](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Topological_transitivity) Scholarpeda article on topological dynamics by Kolyada and Snoha.

In all of these sources, a topologically mixing dynamical system is required to be continuous. The accepted answer is obviously discontinuous, so it is not topologically mixing by the standard definitions.

I am unaware of any sources which would allow discontinuous topological dynamical systems.

Comment: Do you know of a continuous such map?

Comment: @AnnieLeKatsu: Sure, but it is already given by pem, whose answer, I believe you should upvote and accept. This is a very standard example.

Comment: Now I'm interested though.... is Goodboy's map measurable?

Comment: Certainly: just think of the preimage of an interval

Comment: @AnnieLeKatsu: Picewise-linear maps are clearly measurable. As a rule of thumb, to construct a non-measurable map (or a subset) one has to invoke something like Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @AnnieLeKatsu: The problem with the map is that it is discontinuous even in the interior of the cube, whenever $1/2$ is one of the coordinates.

Comment: Oh I must have missed something then.... but it would still have dense orbits and "mix" though?

Comment: @AnnieLeKatsu: Yes it would, but the issue is the definition of a topologically mixing map. The standard definition requires continuity.