# Question about an example of topologocally mixing map

Tags: general-topology, chaos-theory

How to show that the doubling map $T:[0,1) \to [0,1)$ given by $T =2x $ (mod $1$) is topologically mixing?

Topologically mixing means that for any pair of open sets $U,V$ there is a large $N$ such that $T^n(U)\cap V\neq\emptyset$ for all $n\geq N$

Comment: This might need some more detail; are $U,V$ just supposed to be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$? Is $T$ supposed to be a map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? Because if that's the case, the way I understand $T$, its image is actually contained in $[0,1)$, so $T^n(U)$ will be contained in $[0,1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all open $U$, so the map cannot be mixing. Am I misinterpreting your map?

Comment: @LukasMiristwhisky $T$ is a map from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ and $U,V$ are an open, non-empty subsets there. Sorry for the inaccurate wording of the question

Answer (score 1):

For each $x\in [0,1)$ and each positive integer $n$ we have $T^n(x)=2^nx (\operatorname{mod} 1)$. There are non-negative integers $N$ and $i<2^N$ such that $W=[i2^{-N},(i+1)2^{-N})\subset U$. Then $T^n(U)\supset T^n(W)=[0,1)$.